# Apache redirect url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

After rebuilding my site some URLs (where contents no more exist) have to be redirected to the /index.php. In the older version I had an index.php in the /hu/fulbeloves+fulbevaloval/ directory, that directory does not exist now. I would like to redirect the requests as follows:

1. /hu/fulbeloves+fulbevaloval/ => /index.php?q=hu/fulbeloves-fulbevaloval/
2. /hu/fulbeloves+fulbevaloval/index.php?placeid=1234 => /index.php?q=hu/fulbeloves-fulbevaloval/index.php?placeid=1234

the first case works properly, but if index.php is in the URL then it fails with 404 (Not Found)

my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks for the advices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following. Make sure your htaccess Rules file and index.php files are present inside root directory. Also in your 2nd shown rewritten url `/index.php?q=hu/fulbeloves-fulbevaloval/index.php?placeid=1234` it can't be the case so I have instead rewritten it to `/index.php?q=hu/fulbeloves-fulbevaloval&placeid=1234` with 1st rule here.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^+]*)\+([^/]*)/index.\.php\?(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?q=%1-%2/index.php&%3 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The 404 response by index.php (and all .php requests) came because of the VirtualHost setting:
`ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/srv/`

Solved after changing it to `ProxyPassMatch ^/(index\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/srv/`

Comment: still 404 for index.php

Comment: @ArpadHart, could you please do let me know what is the sample url you are hitting here?

Comment: https://www.profiloldalak.hu/hu/fulbeloves+fulbevaloval/index.php?place_id=2740

Comment: @ArpadHart, try changing from `RewriteRule ^ /index.php?q=%1/%2-%3/&%4 [L]
` TO `RewriteRule ^ index.php?q=%1/%2-%3/&%4 [L]` once?

Comment: And that was OK: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]`, because in the new URL we have "-" instead of "+".

Comment: @ArpadHart, Sorry I didn't get it, could you please elaborate more on this one.

Comment: We have to redirect all URLs containing one or more "+", so "+" should be replaced with "-" (show URL with "-" in the browser) , and because this file does not exist these URL should be redirected to index.php .

Comment: What I dont understand is that /hu/fulbeloves+fulbevaloval/index.html?placeid=1234 works, but /hu/fulbeloves+fulbevaloval/index.php?placeid=1234 is alwasy 404

Comment: @ArpadHart, in your 2nd shown rewritten url `/index.php?q=hu/fulbeloves-fulbevaloval/index.php?placeid=1234` it can't be the case so I have instead rewritten it to `/index.php?q=hu/fulbeloves-fulbevaloval&placeid=1234` could you please confirm on same

Comment: @ArpadHart, could you please try my edited rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: it doesn't work for /hu/fulbeloves+fulbevaloval/index.php?placeid=1234

Comment: @ArpadHart, that's what I was trying to say, a URL can't have 2 `?` in it. So try to make your url like `/index.php?q=hu/fulbeloves-fulbevaloval/index.php&placeid=1234` etc? Please confirm once.

Comment: this is a misunderstanding. The old URL (indexed by crawlers) is that: /hu/fulbeloves+fulbevaloval/index.php?placeid=1234. This should be redirected. It can be redirected so: /index.php?q=hu/fulbeloves-fulbevaloval/index.php&placeid=1234. But it doesn't work with your rules either.

Comment: @ArpadHart, Ok sure, I have edited my code and taken your code too here, kindly do check it once and let me know how it goes? Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: I think the "." after "index" in the RewriteCond is not needed, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @ArpadHart, No, dot is not needed I caught from index.php to till + so its not needed. So you are hitting: `http://localhost:80/hu/fulbeloves+fulbevaloval/index.php?placeid=1234`? in your browser?

Comment: yes this is the exact url to be redirected

Comment: It does not work with urls like: /xxx/yyyy.php, that means when url has ".php"

Comment: Is it not because of my  VirtualHost setting: `ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/srv/dev.profiloldalak.hu/htdocs/` ??

Comment: Of course that was the problem! changed `^/(index\.php(/.*)?)$` and it works!

Comment: @ArpadHart, could you please edit my answer, that will be clear to me what part you have fixed it? I will approve your edit then.

Comment: Actually your rule for getting placeid as a separeted prameter works now properly!